# How do I solve this error 'Error 404 File or Directory Not Found' in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, http-status-code-404

I successfully host the website and the home page (`Default.aspx`) is loading correctly but after clicking any link button to redirect to another web page the error '404 file or directory not found' comes.
I have tried any solution I found but it gives the same error on all of them.

These are the buttons I have created:

```
<form id="btnform" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="chkRsltBtn" runat="server" Text="Click Here"
         OnClientClick="window.open('CheckResult.aspx','CheckResult');" />
    <asp:Button ID="Buttononclick" runat="server" Text="Button\onClick" 
         OnClick="Buttononclick_Click" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" href="CheckResult.aspx">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:Button ID="B" runat="server" Text="B" PostBackUrl="~/CheckResult.aspx"/>
</form>
```

Comment: We can't answer this with the info you've provided.  The generic answer is:  your links are wrong.  What is an example url that isn't working?  Have you verified that the url is correct?  (because according to the error, it's not).  You should be able to see the url on the page that displays the 404 message.  We need to see that url.  We also need to know where `CheckResult.aspx` is located on your server

Comment: https://bsite.net/seeratfreeasphosting/       This is the url of the website there is a button 'Click Here' that goes to checkResult.aspx webpage but it gives 404 error.

Comment: My recommendation is that you attempt to access that page directly -- type in the url.  You'll see it doesn't resolve.  That means you have an issue with you routing / setup.  Possibly even with whether the requirements for ASP .NET to run.  We can't troubleshoot that for you.  You'll need to dig into your server logs and figure out what the problem is.  Your problem has absolutely nothing to do with the code you've posted above.